# Creating a class by extending DefaultMessage

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to reuse DefautMessage class to send the body to a seda componnet.
My message class is given below with no implementation.

```
public class TestMessage extends DefaultMessage{
}
```

Then I am accesing it as

```
TestMessage msg = new TestMessage();
            msg.setBody(doc);
            getCamelContext().createProducerTemplate().sendBody("seda:inputDoc",msg);
```

But while running the application, I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.dom4j.Document but has value: Message: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@122bfd6 [Document: name testDocument] of type: com.test.TestMessage on: Message: Message: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@122bfd6 [Document: name testDocument]
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you do not need to define your own message class. Simply use camel´s DefaultMessage and set the body and headers you need. Is there a special reason why you tried to extend DefaultMessage?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrap the wrong object
Its expecting org.dom4j.Document but it got org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument

What is doc type??

Comment: I am not wrapping anything for camel. When I just pass the doc to the route it works fine. This exception is coming when I am wrapping the request doc into a Default Message body.